# Running a docker container which uses GPU from kubernetes fails to find the GPU

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, gpu

I want to run a docker container which uses GPU (it runs a cnn to detect objects on a video), and then run that container on Kubernetes.

I can run the container from docker alone without problems, but when I try to run the container from Kubernetes it fails to find the GPU.

I run it using this command:

```
kubectl exec -it namepod /bin/bash
```

This is the problem that I get:

```
kubectl exec -it tym-python-5bb7fcf76b-4c9z6 /bin/bash
kubectl exec [POD] [COMMAND] is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl exec [POD] -- [COMMAND] instead.
root@tym-python-5bb7fcf76b-4c9z6:/opt# cd servicio/
root@tym-python-5bb7fcf76b-4c9z6:/opt/servicio# python3 TM_Servicev2.py 
 Try to load cfg: /opt/darknet/cfg/yolov4.cfg, weights: /opt/yolov4.weights, clear = 0 
CUDA status Error: file: ./src/dark_cuda.c : () : line: 620 : build time: Jul 30 2021 - 14:05:34 

 CUDA Error: no CUDA-capable device is detected
python3: check_error: Unknown error -1979678822
root@tym-python-5bb7fcf76b-4c9z6:/opt/servicio#
```

**EDIT.**
I followed all the steps on the Nvidia docker 2 guide and downloaded the Nvidia plugin for Kubernetes.

however when I deploy Kubernetes it stays as "pending" and never actually starts. I don't get an error anymore, but it never starts.
The pod appears like this:

```
gpu-pod                       0/1     Pending   0          3m19s
```

**EDIT 2.**

I ended up reinstalling everything and now my pod appears completed but not running. like this.

```
default       gpu-operator-test                          0/1     Completed   0             62m
```

Answering Wiktor.
when I run this command:

```
kubectl describe pod gpu-operator-test
```

I get:

```
Name:         gpu-operator-test
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         pdi-mc/192.168.0.15
Start Time:   Mon, 09 Aug 2021 12:09:51 -0500
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: 968e49d27fb3d86ed7e70769953279271b675177e188d52d45d7c4926bcdfbb2
              cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 
              cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 
Status:       Succeeded
IP:           192.168.10.81
IPs:
  IP:  192.168.10.81
Containers:
  cuda-vector-add:
    Container ID:   docker://d49545fad730b2ec3ea81a45a85a2fef323edc82e29339cd3603f122abde9cef
    Image:          nvidia/samples:vectoradd-cuda10.2
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://nvidia/samples@sha256:4593078cdb8e786d35566faa2b84da1123acea42f0d4099e84e2af0448724af1
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Mon, 09 Aug 2021 12:10:29 -0500
      Finished:     Mon, 09 Aug 2021 12:10:30 -0500
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      nvidia.com/gpu:  1
    Requests:
      nvidia.com/gpu:  1
    Environment:       <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-9ktgq (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-9ktgq:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:                      <none>
```

I'm using this configuration file to create the pod

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: gpu-operator-test
spec:
  restartPolicy: OnFailure
  containers:
  - name: cuda-vector-add
    image: "nvidia/samples:vectoradd-cuda10.2"
    resources:
      limits:
         nvidia.com/gpu: 1
```

Comment: Please don't post textual content as screenshots; it impairs searching, is hard to read, and is explicitly mentioned in the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. You should also ban the use of "it doesn't work" from your vocabulary when asking for help, because it doesn't say what, exactly, did not work of what, exact, attempt you made to fix your cluster

Comment: you're right, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Hello @FelipeSerna. Could you tell us which version of k8s are you using?

Comment: I'm using Kubernetes 1.21.3

Comment: Hello @FelipeSerna. Could you `kubectl describe` the pending Pod and also check for any relevant logs from it? Please, edit your question with the outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing two topics here:

1. The error you saw at the beginning:

---

```
kubectl exec [POD] [COMMAND] is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl exec [POD] -- [COMMAND] instead.
```

Means that you tried to use a deprecated version of the `kubectl exec` command. The proper syntax is:

```
$ kubectl exec (POD | TYPE/NAME) [-c CONTAINER] [flags] -- COMMAND [args...]
```

See [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#exec) for more details.

2. According the the [official docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/gpu-operator/getting-started.html) the `gpu-operator-test` pod should run to completion:
   [image]

You can see that the pod's status is `Succeeded` and also:

---

```
 State:          Terminated
   Reason:       Completed
   Exit Code:    0
```

`Exit Code: 0` means that the specified container command completed successfully.

More details can be found in the [official docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/gpu-operator/getting-started.html).